# Excel VBA - How to select a column by Column Number and insert a new column in one sheet after compared with two different worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code that will compare two values in two different worksheets. When condition gets true, it supposed to select a column and insert one column to right in one workbook only (in my case, it should be in `ws`, not in `wsProductivity`).

Though I used `With` & `End With` statement, the selection and insertion were happened in both worksheets that I used for comparison.

The code is below.

```
    'ws & wsProductivity - two sheets that are used for comparison    
count = 0    
For j = 0 To wsProductivity.Range("D3").Value - wsProductivity.Range("D2").Value
            If ws.Cells(4, j).Value <> wsProductivity.Cells(wsProductivity.Range("D1").Value, count + wsProductivity.Range("D2").Value).Value Then
                With ws
                Columns(j).Select
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 'Here is the issue where insertion happened in both ws and wsProductivity sheets
                End With
                ws.Cells(4, j).Value = wsProductivity.Cells(wsProductivity.Range("D1").Value, count + wsProductivity.Range("D2").Value).Value
                count = count + 1
            Else
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next j
```

It would be very much appreciated, if someone could help on it..

Comment: You need a `.` in front of `Columns(j)`... otherwise it's not referring to `With ws`.

Comment: Plus you can avoid `Select`: `.Columns(j).Insert Shift:=....`.

Comment: Your code should not be working at all, you should be getting error `Run-time error '1004':` on the `IF` line of code. You are setting `j = 0` and there is no `0` column.

Comment: What is the value for `ws.Productivity.Range("D2").Value`?

Comment: @BigBen, `Select: .Columns(j).Insert Shift:=....` solved this issue. However, I've tried  in my earlier code with `ws.Activate` before `Columns(j).Select`.  Also solved the issue.
Thank u @BigBen

Comment: @GMalc , Sorry, its my mistake when copy the code. J value should be 10. Thank u for your support.